# Replacing Double Curly Braces with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to prototype the String Object to have a replaceWith Function that make me able to replace directly without using regular expression

```
String.prototype.replaceWith = function(f, t) {
    var regExp = new RegExp("[" + f + "]", "g");
    return this.replace(regExp, t);
};
```

when i tested my code in this string {{Hello}} for example i found that replacing double curly braces is a problem

Test

```
'{{Hello}}'.replaceWith('{{','<<').replaceWith('}}','>>');
```

Result is

```
 "<<<<Hello>>>>"
```

when it should be

```
"<<Hello>>"
```

what is wrong with my script ??

thanks for your help

Comment: See if u can find info on many of the good templating engines now available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[{{]` is the exact same as `[{]` which is the same as just `{` in regex. The square brackets indicate a character class which matches one of any characters within that class. You should just change:

```
"[" + f + "]"
```

To:

```
f
```

So you have:

```
String.prototype.replaceWith = function(f, t) {
    var regExp = new RegExp(f, "g");
    return this.replace(regExp, t);
};
```

Which as Marlin pointed out has the same functionality as `String.prototype.replace` except you don't need to add the `g` modifier, and in my mind `'{{Hello}}'.replace(/{{/g, '<<');` is more concise and understandable to other coders than `'{{Hello}}'.replaceWith('{{', '<<');`.

Answer (score 4):

@PaulPRO is correct, but in chrome you can just use replace:

```
"{{hello}}".replace("}}",">>").replace("{{","<<")
```

Which returns

```
"<<hello>>"
```

What js environment are you using?

Comment: Also in every other browser which supports `JavaScript 1.2` which is about 99.9% of Javascript enabled web browsers :)